# How to prevent a database from being restored?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to prevent a database from being restored with a DDL trigger or something?

The background is that I would like to prevent restoring a database on a test server by a colleague. So far I had a look a DDL trigger but didn't find the right event to react on the restore action.

Comment: Is your colleague restoring the database as SA or is he\she using a different login?

Comment: As this is just a test server everybody is using the SA account. So I can't manage this by setting up permissions for everyone/every DB.

Comment: If everyone uses the SA account won't your colleague just be able to undo anything you do?

Answer (score 4):

Training. Emails. Warnings. Yelling. Complaints to management. Fisticuffs.

Most of these can be part of a proper change-management process.

Address the root cause. Why would someone else be restoring something that you don't want to be restored. Do you need a separate copy of this DB? Does he need a separate copy?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Trying to apply obscure restrictions on the database isn't really fixing the issue, just preventing it from happening.

Comment: +1 - if he is not supposed to restore, pulling him to his manager and HR is the only way to go.

Comment: ...and cattle prods. I always love the use of cattle prods in these kinds of discussions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about keeping constant connections to the database? It wouldn't prevent them, but it might slow them down....

What about something like keeping a database snapshot on the database in question? I'd guess you'd need to drop the snapshot before you can do the restore..... if not a snapshot, replication/log-shipping etc?

Answer (score 0):

As they are logging in as sa this will be a futile effort.  You could however fill up the disks with other data and log files.  Terrible idea, but you asked...